# Optimize a simple function(histogram distance) in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, optimization, image-processing, histogram

I profiled my code and found that this particular function is taking too much time.Any suggestions as to how do I improve this code?

```
function s = compute_distance_hist(h1,h2)
    s = sum(sum(sum(sqrt(h1).*sqrt(h2))));
```

This function calculates histogram distance.

Comment: Is it possible that you are calling this function to often? Or could you precompute say the `sqrt` outside of the loop in which this gets called?

Answer (score 5):

You can save one square root by doing  `sqrt(h1.*h2)` in the most inner parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

A bit more elegant way is

```
sum( sqrt( h1(:).*h2(:) ) )
```

I'm not sure if it's faster though...

One more thing, If the source of trouble is the fact the `compute_distance_hist` is called MANY times, you might want to try and convert it into a function handle to be used instead of calling it explicitly.

For example, instead of

```
while someCondition
    % computations...
    s = compute_distance_hist( a, b );
    % more computations
end
```

How about

```
compute_distance_hist = @( h1, h2 ) sum( sqrt( h1(:).*h2(:) ) );
while someCondition
   % computation
    s = compute_distance_hist( a, b );
    % more computations
end
```

Comment: When talking of speed, anonymous functions are a bad choice. In a benchmark simulation on [ [function call overhead in Matlab/C/Python](http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.2736) ] it has turned out that the call of anonymous functions are two times slower than calling a function defined in a seperate or better the same m-file.